# Unable to output from database with my API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have blog posts setup in my mongoDB. I am trying to pull the posts into my home page to display them. However, when i go to he home page, all I see in the posts are **undefined** for all pieces of data I am trying to pull in. I can add posts to the page when the page is loaded, but the posts already in the mongoDB arent pulling.

Also, I get this error in the console:
`GET http://localhost:3003/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

**home.js file**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $.get("/api/posts", results =>{
        outputPosts(results, $(".postsContainer"));
    })
})

function outputPosts(results, container){
    container.html("");

    results.forEach(result => {
        var html = createPostHtml(result)
        container.append(html);
    })

    if(results.length == 0){
        container.append("<span class='noResults'> no results found.</span>")
    }
}
```

**Post.js** if needed

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const User = require('../../schema/userSchema');
const Post = require('../../schema/PostSchema');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.get("/", (req,res,next) => {
        Post.find()
        .then(results => res.status(200).send(results))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(400);
        })
})

router.post("/", async(req,res,next) => {

    if(!req.body.content){
        console.log("Content param not sent with request");
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

    var postData = {
        content: req.body.content,
        postedBy: req.session.user
    }

    Post.create(postData)
    .then(async newPost => {
        newPost = await User.populate(newPost, { path: "postedBy"})
    
        res.status(201).send(newPost);
    
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(400);
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

**common.js**

```
 $.post("/api/posts",data,postData => {
        var html = createPostHtml(postData);
        console.log(html);
        $(".postsContainer").prepend(html);
        textbox.val("");
        button.prop("disabled", true);
    })
})

function createPostHtml(postData){
    
    var postedBy = postData.postedBy;
    var displayName = postedBy.firstName + " " + postedBy.lastName;
    var timestamp = " to do later";

    return `<div class='post'>
                <div class='mainContentContainer'>
                    <div class='userImageContainer'>
                        <img src='${postedBy.profilePic}'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='postContentContainer'>
                        <div class='header'>
                            <a href='/profile/${postedBy.username}' class='displayName'>${displayName}</a>
                            <span class='username'>@${postedBy.username}</span>
                            <span class='date'>${timestamp}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='postBody'>
                            <span>${postData.content}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='postFooter'>
                            <div class="postButtonContainer">
                                <button>
                                    <i class='far fa-comment'></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="postButtonContainer">
                                <button>
                                    <i class='far fas-retweet'></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="postButtonContainer">
                                <button>
                                    <i class='far fa-heart'></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>`;

}
```

Comment: What are you even asking? "... when i go to he home page, all I see in the posts are undefined ... BUT the page will load any post I enter once im on the home page."

Comment: Can you add the `createPostHtml` function to the question?

Comment: Added the createPostHtml function to the code.